# Getting error when trying to secure aspnet core web api with B2C authentication: Unable to retrieve openid config

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to secure my aspnet core web API server by making it authenticate against Azure B2C using user-provided JWT bearer tokens. I've followed some sample code found on official microsoft github pages, but can't seem to get it working.

In my B2C policy, I've got it set to use the default issuer URL format: https:////v2.0/

In my web application, I've got that same URL specified as the Authority in the JWT options.

When I submit an HTTP request to my server, the identity server code fails as it tries to reach out to B2C to fetch the openid-configuration. It fails with the following error ...

```
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://innovativelitfoundry.b2clogin.com/0f55bfb6-6af5-4293-8963-29ae099183cc/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string address, CancellationToken cancel)

InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://innovativelitfoundry.b2clogin.com/0f55bfb6-6af5-4293-8963-29ae099183cc/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager<T>.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
```

Indeed, that URL will not work because it does not appear to be including the policy name, from the used token, in the query string. So, that URL does indeed not work.

I'm unsure how to make the code provide that policy name in the query string, though? Or should it be doing that automatically?

Here is the code, in my aspnet core web api application, where I configure the authentication settings ...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

        services
            .AddAuthentication(ConfigureAuthentication)
            .AddJwtBearer(ConfigureJwt);

        services
            .AddCors();

        services
            .AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services
            .AddSingleton(Configuration);
    }

    private void ConfigureAuthentication(AuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }

    private void ConfigureJwt(JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        var tenant = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];

        options.Audience = Configuration["AzureAd:ApplicationId"];
        options.Authority = $"https://innovativelitfoundry.b2clogin.com/{tenant}/v2.0/";
    }
```

Does anybody perhaps know what I may be doing incorrectly here? How can I get my aspnet core web api application to correctly pull down that openid configuration document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `options.Authority` to an authority URL that includes the policy ID:

`options.Authority = $"https://innovativelitfoundry.b2clogin.com/{tenant}/{policy}/v2.0/";`

As long as you have set [the issuer claim for all policies to the issuer URL that doesn't contain the policy ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517259/7378174), then your API application can download the configuration document for any policy and then validate tokens that are issued for all policies.

Comment: Yay! That does it. I think I understand how all this works a bit better now.